# Why my ground faces looked like it's broken while i render it?

Tags: rendering, faces

But if I pull up the faces much more higher, then it seems like it's okay

I pulled up one face much more higher to show it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: are you sure you have no hidden objects or ovjects on different layers?

Comment: It's hard to tell what it is supposed to look like, is it the brown surface or the white one, or the yellowish one, or the black one that is the problem? Do you have any overlapping surfaces? or maybe they are so close that they are creating some form of Z-fighting. It is hard to tell with the existing information.